# How can I put all the values in the list into a list box on separate lines? Python

Tags: python, listbox

I have the following code which creates a list box and populates it with data from a MySQL query.

```
self.listbox = Listbox(self)
self.data = ['All Accounts']

sql = "SELECT AccNo FROM accounts"
curs.execute(sql)

numrows = curs.fetchall()
self.data.append(numrows)
for i in self.data:
    self.listbox.insert(END, i)
    self.listbox.grid(row=8, column= 0, columnspan=3, rowspan=8)
```

The data shows up in the list box but all on one line. How can I change the code so that it populates the list box with each item in the list on a different line in the list box?

Thank you for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the problem is that you really only have one entry in your list, the entire contents of sql statement is assigned to "numrows". When you append numrows to your self.data list, it's doing that as one big, single entry.  You're doing the equivalent of this:

```
self.data.append(curs.fetchall())
```

Which is just passing the sql return directly to your list.  You'll need to parse the return info from your sql statement before adding it to the list, instead of just appending it directly to the list.

Comment: I have done some research into parsing tuples in python and on how to split them however I can not seem to come up with a solution. Would you happen to know how I am able to parse the return info?

Comment: Can you add an example of the data being returned.

Comment: This is what I get if I print numrows:
((None,), (None,), ('10001',))

Comment: To do basic splits you do something like: numrows = numrows.split(','), which will take your data and break it up based on where your delimiter is.  You could then access the data by passing a location like numrows[0] which would give you ((None   That probably isn't totally what you want, so my suggestion would be to do some cleaning up of your contents before splitting. Maybe find/replace all parenthesis so you have your values and commas only?

Comment: Unfortunately, i'm not familiar with fetching and working with sql data in a python context but I assume you can apply the same basic data-cleaning concepts to it that you would to any imported string data.